# Scroll multiple div at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to scroll multiple `div` at the same time. when i scroll in one `div`, i would like to report the scroll in all div.

I create the div dynamically. So i use the function `document.getElementsByClassName sub-category-container` to get all my elements. And i try to get the current scroll of the current div to defer the value.

I can not get it to work through the class names. 
Do you have a solution?

Here is an example of what I try to do :
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VVaEq/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you are using jQuery already Use [`class selector`](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/). Try this:

```
var subCatContainer = $(".sub-category-container");
subCatContainer.scroll(function() {
    subCatContainer.scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/VVaEq/2/)**

Answer (score 2):

Based on your JSFiddle,

```
$(".sub-category-container").scroll(function() {
    for(var i in subCatContainer)
        $(subCatContainer[i]).scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VVaEq/5/)