# AngularJS: use jquery with multiple ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I recently posted a question concerning the possibility of different scroller `div` with the same class name. It works perfectly. 
Here is the link of the thread: [Scroll multiple div at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863324/scroll-multiple-div-at-the-same-time/22863500?noredirect=1#22863500)

Lately, I've made ​​changes in my code to make all the `div` dynamic (with `ng-repeat`). Since these changes, my jquery function no longer works. I think the javascript is executed before my various `ng-repeat` is completed.

My function to scroll on all the container with the same class name :

```
var subCatContainer = $(".sub-category-container");
subCatContainer.scroll(function() {
    subCatContainer.scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
});
```

Is there a solution in order to wait for my `ng-repeat`? in a directive?

To complete my explanation, I created a : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cm5xx/)

Comment: just wrap your jQuery that is floating in the air with a document ready

Comment: I wrap my JQuery in my JSFiddle and it works. However it doesn't work my in my app. Do you know why? I have too much data?

Comment: how is your data coming in? from a request? can you post an example?

Comment: Yes from a request! i use `$http`.

Comment: right so you are probably calling to the function before any data has populated into those divs therefore it does not work, you have to call the function after data has been populated...

Comment: Yes, i'm agree with you. This is precisely the point of my question (it is certainly badly worded). How to call the function `scrollableContainer var = $ (" scrollable-container. ")` after data has been populated. Do you have any idea?

Comment: if you are using `$http` then check this out https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/service/$http theres a success callback that you can use

Comment: I created a directive that catch the last element of my `ng-repeat` and i update my var `subCatContainer = $(".sub-category-container");`. This post help me : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471129/angularjs-ng-repeat-finish-event).
Thank you for your help!!!!